# I want to reinstall the previous version of ubuntu to a pc that has dual boot Ubuntu and windows

Tags: dual-boot, reinstall

So I upgraded Ubuntu, but I'm having a lot of trouble. I want to reinstall the older version of Ubuntu, which was working like a charm. However, I don't want to create problems with windows. my question is that in the first option in the picture will erase windows as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first option will eliminate *just* Ubuntu. The third option will wipe the disk, including Windows.

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; but you can re-install Ubuntu Desktop (*and flavors*) without losing data files, (*and with some restrictions*) having your *manually installed* packages auto-reinstall.  Being specific as to what Ubuntu product/release helps us to better answer you.

Comment: @guiverc I posted a picture of the screen, Im new at this. So the current version is 22.04.1lts and i want to reinstall 20.04.5lts

Comment: @matigo Are you sure? so it will be replace with the older version and the dual boot option will be there?

Comment: If it's a new install and you don't want to keep anything; I'd likely follow advice from @matigo (*clean* installs are the fastest/easiest & least likely to have issues), but if you've made configuration changes you want to keep, have added packages (the *manually installed* I mentioned) you'd like to have auto-re-installed I'd use *Something else*, select your partitions (ensuring you don't have *format* checked for any) & install that way which triggers the repair/re-install option. FYI you didn't state if Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Desktop or Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Server but I'm guessing desktop

Comment: Largely FYI... but the *repair* or re-install options is one of the features I '*love*' about Ubuntu.. Even if you have only a single partition, you can re-install Ubuntu Desktop systems when you make package mistakes or make many stupid mistakes & have the system back where it was in usually less than 15 minutes (*sometimes faster than restoring backups, but always have backups too as mistakes are easy to make; the lack of format triggers the repair for `ubiquity` or `calamares` installer scripts with Ubuntu; I've assumed your 22.04.1 ISO is a `ubiquity` from your picture).

Comment: The install type I mentioned requires internet (*so as to install the manually installed packages not found on ISOs*) & as system directories are erased, it's only great for desktop installs (*not server apps that often store configs in system directories; ie. restore from backups still required for any server apps*), and it allows you to switch release too (*though as some apps are only available for some releases; error on packages not available can be expected*) & not 3rd party packages, but packages added from Ubuntu repositories (*errors on 3rd party can be expected but ignore*)

Comment: @guiverc So I made a bootable usb with ubuntu 20.04.5lts, to install and replace the new vertion. So I want to keep windows and the dual boot. Does the first option in the picture will do that? So yeah i dont care if the ubuntu partition gets clean out to reinstall ubuntu, and yes i will have it connected to the internet.

Comment: fyi:  I write about the *repair installation* (or I like *Upgrade via re-install*) process [here](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743) if interested (*on this site too many places; but that link is easiest to find for me*) where it's called "*Install using existing partition*" though please note the intended audience of that page was QA (*Quality Assurance*) testers & not end-users..  Some answers on this site were intended for end-users, but I find harder to find sorry.  There can be complexities going backwards (older release) but *app* specific